# Why does fields in injected class become null - JavaFX with Spring

Tags: java, spring, javafx, dependency-injection, gluon

I got some null pointer exceptions when I try to access the fields from an injected object. I'm going to show a simple example. I'm using lokbok annotations `@Getter` and `@Setter`.

I have a simple class.

```
public class MyClass {

    /*
     * Field
     */
    private @Getter @Setter String myName;

    public MyClass(){

    }
}
```

Then I another class

```
public class AnotherClass {

        /*
         * Field
         */
        private MyClass myClass;

        public AnotherClass(){
             ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
             myClass = context.getBean("myClass", MyClass.class);
             ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();

             myClass.setMyName("Hello");
        }
    }
```

If I access the field `myName` from a third  class, like this.

```
public class ThirdClass {

        /*
         * Field
         */
        private MyClass myClass;

        public ThirdClass(){
             ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
             myClass = context.getBean("myClass", MyClass.class);
             ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();

             System.out.println(myClass.getMyName());
        }
    }
```

It will print out `null` as output. I have created my Beans.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Create my class -->
    <bean id="myClass" class="MyClass"></bean>


</beans>
```

**Questions:**

Should it behave like that?

Have I missed something if I don't want to have `null`?

Software being used:

- JavaFX 8
- Java 8
- Gluon-Ignite Spring 1.0.2
- Lombok 1.18.8

Comment: If you want 2 objects to "be connected", they need to be created by the same context object (or context using the original one as parent). Calling `close` will result in `IllegalStateException`s when trying to use the later though.

Comment: @fabian How can I connect the same context object in this case? I thought DI would do the job for me so the fields would have the same address.

Comment: @fabian I found a solution. Please give me a reply if its a good solution or it can be done better? :)

Comment: `AnotherClass` and `ThirdClass` should be (prototype) beans. If you do need to manually fill the `myClass` fields instead of injecting the bean, it should also be possible to inject the context...

Comment: Please don't edit in solutions. Instead, talk to @fabian, have the question reopened so you can add an answer below if you believe it's different than the duplicated answers.

Comment: @fabian i don't understand. Can you show an example ?

Comment: There are a ton of tutorials out there. (Comments are insufficient to provide an example anyways.) E.g. [for injecting beans to other beans](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-injection), [Tutorial explaining difference between prototype and singleton](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm)